# Bash completion doesn't work for MSYS bash. Regex syntax error

Tags: regex, bash, msys, bash-completion

I tried to install bash-completion for MSYS bash, but it seems it contains some syntax errors.
It fails with the following message

```
bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 625: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 625: syntax error near `^(\'
bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 625: `    if [[ $cur =~ ^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]; then'
```

here is the code that fails

```
# Complete variables.
# @return  True (0) if variables were completed, 
#          False (> 0) if not.
_variables()
{
    if [[ $cur =~ ^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]; then
        [[ $cur == *{* ]] && local suffix=} || local suffix=
        COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -P ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -S "$suffix" -v -- \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ) )
        return 0
    fi
    return 1
}
```

Comment: probably that the above code is for a later version of bash, rather than "BASH_VERSION='3.1.17(1)-release'" (at least in the MSYS I have installed). Any Bash experts care to comment? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the beta version (1.99) of bash-completion, you can try the latest stable instead (1.3)

If you really need the beta version you need quotes around the regular expression `^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$` in the line `if [[ $cur =~ ^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]; then` handling of the operator =~ is different depending on bash version (IIRC prior 3.2 quotes are required)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add quotes to all regexes but run into other problems. So I installed stable and it worked just fine.

Comment: As far as I remember there was only one regular expresion in the entire file. What other problems ?

Comment: I had another look, there are quite a lot of regular expresions in the 1.99 version. What other probles did you encounter ?